# if else condition is not working in foreach

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, foreach

I am using if else in a foreach loop and binding that value with the container but I don't understand Why if else condition is not working in foreach it is showing if else statement in html page like if({detailInfo.condition} !== ""){} but condition is not working? how can I use if else  in a div element?

```
async function renderViewDetails(data, dataTableOrders) {
      let ordersDetails = data.group_id;
      var detailInfos = dataTableOrders;

      let html =
        `<div class="viewDetailModal">
          <div class="detailButtonModal">
            <p class="viewOrderId">ID:</p>
            <p class="orderdetailsid viewOrderId">${data.id}</p>
            <p class="coinviewDetail">${data.coin}</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="rb-container">
            <ul class="rb">`;

      detailInfos.forEach(detailInfo => {
        if (detailInfo.group_id == ordersDetails) {
          let htmlSegment = `
                  <li class="rb-item timelimeVertical" ng-repeat="itembx">
                    <div class="tradingOrdersInfo">
                    <p class="orderDetailDate">${detailInfo.openedAt}</p>
            
                    <div class="tradeOrderType">
                    <p class="viewDetailOrderType">${detailInfo.type}</p>
                    <button id="showMoreLess_${detailInfo.id}" 
                     data-order-id="${detailInfo.id}" 
                     class="viewDetailOrderButton">View 
                     More</button>
                    </div>
            
                                    
                    <div id="showme_${detailInfo.id}" style="display:none";>
            
                    <div class="tradeOrderEntry">
                    <div>
                    <p class="orderDetailQuantity">Quantity:</p>
                    <p class="orderDetailQuantityValue">${detailInfo.volume}</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="tradeOrdervaluePrice">
                   <p class="orderPnlInner"> &nbsp; ${detailInfo.group_pnl}</p>
                   <p class="pnlInnerLabel">PNL</p>
                   </div>
                   </div>
            
            
                   <div class="tradeOrderEntry tradeOrderEntryValue">
                   <div>
                   <p class="detailEntryValue entryOpa ">TP Target</p>
                   <p class="detailEntryValue entryOpa">Entry Target</p>
                   </div>
            
 if({detailInfo.condition} !== null){
                   <div>
                   <p class="detailEntryValueR viewPadd">{detailInfo.condition}</p>
                   <p class="detailEntryValueR"> {detailInfo.condition} </p>
                   </div>
                   </div>
            }
            
                   <div class="tradeOrderEntry tradeOrderEntryValue">
                   <div>
                   <p class="detailEntryValue entryOpa">Expire</p>
                   </div>
            
                  
                     </div>
            
                  </div>
                  </li>`

          html += htmlSegment;
        }
      });
      html += `</ul></div></div>`;

      let container = document.querySelector('.orders-details-info');
      container.innerHTML = html;

      }
```

Comment: You can't have `if` statements inside template literals' backticks. Only expressions are allowed inside the `${}`

Comment: Instead of `if ({detailInfo.condition} !== null) { "<your html>" }`, use ternary `${ detailInfo.condition !== null ? "<div> ...... </div>" : " "}`

Comment: Can you add an edit to the question? You are probably missing the quotes/bacticks around the HTML inside the ternary: `<p class="detailEntryValue entryOpa">Entry Target</p> </div> ${ detailInfo.condition !== null ? \`<div> ...... </div>\` : ""} <div class="tradeOrderEntry tradeOrderEntryValue">`

Comment: Here's a snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/xkLtj5d6/1/

Comment: i am getting this error on console Unexpected token '<'       ${detailInfo.condition !== null ?  <div class="tradeOrderEntry tradeOrderEntryValue"> <div>
<p class="detailEntryValue entryOpa">Condition</p>
</div>
<div><p class="detailEntryValueR">${detailInfo.condition}</p>
</div>
</div> : "" 
 }

Comment: Please check the snippet in the above comment for the correct syntax. You need to wrap the HTML inside the ternary with backticks. `\``

Comment: @adiga thanks It worked. i really appreciate your help